# Create method to return dataset

Tags: methods, dataset, return

I'm trying to create a method to pass an ID number to a stored proc and return a dataset, this is what I have written so far, I am receiving an error message saying:  "Not all code paths return a value", I'm not sure how I finish this.  Would appreciate help!

```
public Int32 gvProjDetailsBind(Int32 ProjID)
    {           

        String strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project_Tracker"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connDetails = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmdDetails = new SqlCommand("USP_SelectProject", connDetails);
        cmdDetails.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdDetails.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectNumber", ProjID);
        SqlDataAdapter daDetails = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDetails);
        DataSet dsDetails = new DataSet();
        daDetails.Fill(dsDetails);
        gvProjDetails.DataSource = dsDetails;
        gvProjDetails.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here...

1) Your method doesn't return anything.

You've declared a return type of `Int32` but never return any value.  The compiler won't allow this, because any code calling this method expects a value to be returned.  So somewhere, likely at the end, you need a `return` statement which returns a value.  (In this case an integer value.)

2) You claim you want to return a `DataSet`

The return type you've declared is `Int32`, not `DataSet`.  If you want to return a `DataSet` then you need to change that return type in the method signature accordingly, and then (at the end of the method) return the `DataSet`.  Something like this:

```
public DataSet gvProjDetailsBind(Int32 ProjID)
{
    // the rest of the code
    return dsDetails;
}
```

3) You're not separating your concerns

You claim that you want the method to return the `DataSet`, but at the end of the method you already *use* the `DataSet`:

```
gvProjDetails.DataSource = dsDetails;
gvProjDetails.DataBind();
```

What is code calling this method going to *do* with this `DataSet`?  Normally the UI code would call a method like this to get the data and then bind it to elements (in this case `gvProjDetails`).  You seem to be combining these concepts into a single block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return value. You can return 0 for example.
return 0;
should be enough. But what do you realy want to return?
In case of dsDetails, you should pass an out parameter and return dsDetails this way.